# How to secure dynamic resources in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

In my **Spring Boot** application, user images are saved in the file system and added the path in resource handlers as

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations("file:/home/imgs/profiles/");
```

I have added JWT security for some of the rest services along with `/uploads/**` 
as `.antMatchers("/uploads/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`

but this `/uploads/**` is not checking for security. it is accepting requests from postman without auth token

The path to the resource is as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/uploads/1302caa0-570d-46ed-ae69-372b48c58a3a/74b780b573f149709776e800a659c83e.jpg
```

How can I configure security for this dynamic resource?

Comment: How did you implemented the JWT authentication ? Because by writing `.antMatchers("/uploads/**").permitAll()` you explicitly exclude `/uploads/**` requests for any security check.

Answer (score 1):

According to you configuration you have permitted access to all for user images.

If you to restrict access to only authenticated users, you can just use following configuration:

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

If you want more granular control for images security, you can use following configuration(for example):

```
.antMatchers("/uploads/**")
.hasRole("IMAGE_USER_ROLE")
.anyRequest()
.authenticated()
```